# vyosのNAT設定について

Tags: network

[image: 構成イメージ]
ネットワークの勉強の為、vyosの設定を行っています。 
上記の構成で、PCからvyosを経由してインターネットへの通信を行えるようにしたいです。

■問題点
1.現在の設定では、PCからvyos間のPing応答はあります。
2.vyosからインターネットへの通信(ping 8.8.8.8)は応答はあります。
3.PCからインターネットへの通信(ping 8.8.8.8)が失敗します。PCのFWはOffにしています。

■設定（login user情報は削除）

```
set interfaces ethernet eth0 address 'dhcp'
set interfaces ethernet eth0 duplex 'auto'
set interfaces ethernet eth0 smp-affinity 'auto'
set interfaces ethernet eth0 speed 'auto'
set interfaces ethernet eth1 address '10.0.2.7/24'
set interfaces ethernet eth1 duplex 'auto'
set interfaces ethernet eth1 smp-affinity 'auto'
set interfaces ethernet eth1 speed 'auto'
set interfaces loopback 'lo'
set nat destination rule 10 destination address '10.0.2.5'
set nat destination rule 10 inbound-interface 'eth0'
set nat destination rule 10 source address '0.0.0.0/0'
set nat destination rule 10 translation address '10.0.2.7'
set nat source rule 10 outbound-interface 'eth0'
set nat source rule 10 source address '10.0.2.0/24'
set nat source rule 10 translation address 'masquerade'
set protocols static route 0.0.0.0/0 next-hop 'y.y.y.y'
set service ssh 'disable-password-authentication'
set service ssh port '2022'
set system config-management commit-revisions '100'
set system console device ttyS0 speed '9600'
set system host-name 'vyos'
set system name-server '157.7.180.133'
set system name-server '163.44.76.148'
set system ntp server '0.pool.ntp.org'
set system ntp server '1.pool.ntp.org'
set system ntp server '2.pool.ntp.org'
set system syslog global facility all level 'notice'
set system syslog global facility protocols level 'debug'
set system time-zone 'Asia/Tokyo'
```

最初はnatの設定が無かったので、下記ページを参照してnat sourceの設定を追記しました。
[vyos ユーザーガイド Source NAT](http://wiki.vyos-users.jp/%E3%83%A6%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B6%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AC%E3%82%A4%E3%83%89)

おそらくNAT（nat destination）あたりの設定が誤っているのではないかと思うのですが、詳しい方はいらっしゃいますでしょうか。

Comment: `set nat destination rule 10 ...` の部分(port forwarding from outside to inside)は必要なのでしょうか？ destination port の設定がありませんが…

Comment: nat destinationの部分については、nat sourceだけではつながらなかった為、なんとなく追記していました。
調べたところ、使用しているcloud service の仕様？で、提供されている独自のAPIでNICポートのファイアーウォールを操作する必要がありました。
現在はインターネットへの通信が可能な状態です。
お騒がせ致しました。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/71756